# Prevent subscriber saving in observer newsletter_subscriber_save_before Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I created an Observer to monitor the event subscriber_save_before. In this observer I handle a new field, the value of that is saved, but if some errors occurs I wanna the record not to be saved and to display only my error message. The throwException seems not to do the trick. The only method I think could work is to force the email field to null but wasn't able to achieve this.
In the subscriberController.php (Mage Core) I have this:

```
$email = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

        try {
            if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
            }
```

This is my code (not working):

```
    public function NewsletterSaveSubscriber($observer)
{
    $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
    $name = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_name');



    // server side validation
    // no name specified
    if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($name), 'NotEmpty')) {

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

        try {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('The name field cannot be empty!'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->addException($e, Mage::helper('newsletter')->__('There was a problem: %s', $e->getMessage()));
        }
     $observer->getRequest()->setPost('email', ''); // this code doesn't work
     Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('email', ''); // this too 

          // Ohh nooo! The subscriber is stored :-(
        return $this;
    }


    // save the name
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a redirect statement. Do you want to redirect when you get to exception with invalid email or you want your code to execute and on next page display your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your probem:

```
//Error Message
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$session->getMessages(true);
$session->addError(Mage::helper('cartware_automaticreview')->__('Could´t save.'));  

// Ohh nooo! The subscriber is not stored :)            
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction()->setFlag('',Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH,true);
$controller->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));
return;
```

Good luck!